# PHP-CRUD-API - best way for authentication

Tags: php, authentication

I'm using PHP-CRUD-API and everything works perfectly. I'm thinking about simple in use authentication, what are your referring? I'm front-end dev, so I'm looking very easy to implementation script.

Comment: Judging by this article (https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/11/php-crud-api-now-supports-authorization-and-validation/) PHP-CRUD-API now supports authorization and validation

Comment: ye, but is about authorization. Im looking for solution, where other people cant access api.

Comment: I might be wrong, but it does not seem to be designed as a cms or other type of open access *website*. But you can add .htaccess authentication to your project: https://www.google.com/search?q=.htaccess+authentication

Comment: thanks, i will read about htaccess, maybe someone else will answer with other solution

Comment: @DainisAbols but there is way to block way to put the api request from http browser? I will only need api to load data via ajax (there is way to lock  by any key or smth?)

Comment: An ajax request is a form-like request from a browser submitted by javascript. To limit requests for API you probably want to assign an API key/sha/salt and check for json/xml-type requests only. That can be validated by reading ie the request headers.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [PHP-API-AUTH](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-api-auth), it is a "Single file PHP script that adds authentication to a PHP-CRUD-API project". It does exactly what you ask for.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of PHP-CRUD-API.

Comment: Is it possible to add multiple users to the authentication?

Comment: @MaartenHeideman In [PHP-CRUD-API](https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api) v2 the authorization and authentication system has been redone and now you can easily add users using a text file.

Comment: Hey Mev, 

Please guide how can i authenticate api so only people with my secret key can access it only...